# Change paper tab to drop down menu list in Polymer js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, user-interface, polymer

Please help me in converting the paper tab to paper drop down menu in polymer JS. On hover of Top menu, drop down should come up with the list of values.

Activity
    
    
        Execution

```
<paper-tab class="navTbs onHoverT" link="" style="padding: 0 12px 0 12px;" role="tab" noink="" aria-disabled="false"
    tabindex="-1">
    <a href="#/14" tabindex="-1">Execution Plan</a>
</paper-tab>


<paper-tab class="navTbs onHoverT" link="" style="padding: 0 12px 0 12px;" role="tab" noink="" aria-disabled="false"
    tabindex="-1">
    <a href="#/15" tabindex="-1">Hierarchy</a>
</paper-tab>
<paper-tab class="navTbs onHoverT" link="" style="padding: 0 12px 0 12px;" role="tab" noink="" aria-disabled="false"
    tabindex="-1">
    <a href="#/16" tabindex="-1">Event</a>
</paper-tab>
<paper-tab class="navTbs onHoverT" link="" style="padding: 0 12px 0 12px;width:70px" role="tab" noink="" aria-disabled="false"
    tabindex="-1">
    <a href="#/17" tabindex="-1">view</a>
</paper-tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `paper-drop-down-menu` instead check this link where all the elements from polymer are kept,

[Link for the example and demo](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu)

Comment: i tried using paper drop down however the list isnt dispalyed